# May I search among some fields, but use another field's matching score for sorting?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some documents like this

```
{"id":1,"city":"London","content":"soccer","continent":"Europe"},
{"id":2,"city":"New York","content":"basketball","continent":"North America"},
{"id":3,"city":"Tokyo","content":"baseball","continent":"Asia"},
...
```

I need to search keywords among some fields(excluding `city` field), e.g. a query like

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [ //SHOULD_CLAUSE
        "match": {
          "continent": "America"
        },
        "term": {
          "content": "soccer"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

To make the results more "personalized", I want to make matched documents whose `city` field is the same as the visiting user's `city` property. 
However, if I make `city` as a query field(something like `"match":{"city":"Tokyo"}`) in `should` boolean clause, it may return some documents that only match the `city` field, which mismatch the fields I need to search. When using `boost` to make `city` field more "important" for sorting things goes worse.
How can I achieve my goal?

It seems that a possible way write the `SHOULD_CLAUSE` part twice and make one of it combined with `city` clause using `and`

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [{
        "bool": {
          "must": [{
            "bool": {
              SHOULD_CLAUSE
            }
          }, {
            "match": {
              "city": {
                "query": "Tokyo",
                "boost": 4.0
              }
            }
          }]
        }
      }, {
        "bool": {
          SHOULD_CLAUSE
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

But under the real circumstance the `SHOULD_CLAUSE` part may be more complicated and the whole query seems too long to write. I wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: did you have a look at must clause ? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Comment: Hi, juliendangers, I've edited my question adding some samples to make it more clear to understand, and gave my own answer which seems not so perfect. I think only `must` clause may not be enough to achieve my goal. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is SHOULD_CLAUSE the same in your example ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have only result matching your user city, you should wrap your should query into a must query, something like :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [{
        "bool": {
          "should": [{
            SHOULD_CLAUSE_1
          }, {
            SHOULD_CLAUSE_2
          }]
        }
      }, {
        "match": {
          "city": "Tokyo"
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```